# How can I get the current Crome URL?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing Windows Forms application on C# and trying to get current URL from Chrome in this application. I find active process, and if it's name is "chrome" I try anything, but unsuccessfully. All solutions i've found works only for previous versions of Chrome. As far as I understand, it's better to use Google Chrome Extention for this (but I have never write any of them and I'm superficially familiar with JS).

So, I tried to write an Extension:

manifest.js:

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "URL collector",
"version": "0.11",
"description": "Собирает URL посещенных ресурсов",
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation",
    "scripting"
],
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "app.js"
        ]
    }
]}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
async function getCurrentTab() {
    let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
    return tab;
}
alert(window.getCurrentTab());});
```

app.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
var tab = tabs[0];
console.log(tab.url);
alert(tab.url);});
```

Also I've tried such code:

```
;(function() {
var pushState = history.pushState;
var replaceState = history.replaceState;

history.pushState = function() {
    pushState.apply(history, arguments);
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('pushstate'));
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('locationchange'));
};

history.replaceState = function() {
    replaceState.apply(history, arguments);
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('replacestate'));
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('locationchange'));
};

window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('locationchange'))
});})();

window.addEventListener('locationchange', function(){
    console.log('onlocationchange event occurred!');
    alert(chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab => tab.url));})
```

Everything I have tried in app.js I also tried in background.js and vice versa. And either I did not understand how to track the Extension triggering, or it does not work (probably the second). In general, I tried to catch URL change events, for example, switching tabs or following a link. Well, so far nothing has come of it. Actually, the first question is this: how to make such Extension?

It seems, I totally do not understand the topic, therefore I will also be extremely grateful for links to materials on it.

Well, and the second question is, what is the best way to pass a URL to a Windows Forms application?

Sorry for my English, it seems to be really bad.

Comment: Your current code won't help. Use chrome.webNavigation event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

in my app.js, I'm using `current.Window` rather than `lastFocusedWindow`

```
button_element.addEventListener('click', () => {    
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        arr.push(tabs[0].url)
        localStorage.setItem("example", JSON.stringify(arr) )
        render(arr)
    })
})
```

That works for pushing the current tab to local storage